# wrong with set compare in meta_query - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

The checkboxs saved in db !

The db structure **(wp_postmeta table)** :

```
________________________________________________________________
|               |                                               |
|   meta_key    |                   meta_value                  |
|_______________|_______________________________________________|
|               |                                               | 
| artist_nameaa |   a:2:{i:51;s:2:"51";i:60;s:2:"60";}          |
|_______________|_______________________________________________|
```

two checkboxs has been selected !

i want to find posts where `artist_nameaa` have `51` key in his array

> **51** is an example

Here is my try :

```
    wp_reset_postdata();
    global $post;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'songs',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'artist_nameaa',
                'value' => serialize(array($post->ID=>"$post->ID")),// a:1:{i:51;s:2:"51";}

                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        ),
        'no_found_rows'         => true,
        'update_post_meta_cache'    => false,
        'update_post_term_cache'    => false,
        'ignore_sticky_posts'       => 1,
        'post__not_in'          => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'        => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    return $query;
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `serialize(array($post->ID=>"$post->ID"))` is actually returning what you expect?

Comment: I found a diffrent way but I did'nt test it . i think we should do like 'tags' #test

Comment: if we had 1 key it works, but not when serialize 1 key and in db 2 key

Answer (score 1):

The `IN()` comparison operator is used to replace several where clauses ([docs)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in). It will ultimately be looking for results that are an exact match.

What you are doing is more of a search. You have no idea where in the serialized string your data set will fall. For this type of search, you should use the `LIKE` operator ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)). You will need to utilize the wildcard flags for this type of search.

From what I can gather about the type of data you are storing, you may want to rethink your storage mechanism. Custom Fields do support multiple values for the same meta key, which would be a quick approach. You could also take advantage of [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) or a custom table ([wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)).

Comment: 51 is id for an artist , and songs have 1 or 2 ,.. artists .

Comment: in each post we have a field for save artists id,

Comment: in artists profile we should display songs of artists

Comment: Yea all makes sense. You should just store the artist id in a separate field each time. Look at the third parameter on `get_post_meta()`